# Is it required to create a NAT instance in every availability zone of a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to figure out what are the best practices to setup a HA VPC

The question relate to:

What is the correct setup of a VPC that is spread all over the AZ of a region, with private and public subnet in every AZ, is it mandatory to create a NAT instance in every public subnet ?

How to achieve HA for the NAT instance, i.e should i wrap it with a autoscale group that ensure that i will have 1 instance up and running ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to have (at least) one NAT node in each AZ.

The reason: If one (or more) AZ is experiencing problems you want outbound connectivity to the Internet to be functional.

You could setup an additional node to monitor the others, or have them monitor each other (though there is a small chance that without a monitoring node you'll get some false positives).

While you could use auto scale groups, AWS provides a good example of nodes checking the others via a simple script, the choice is yours at the end of the day.